# Debian 11 Dummy Output

Tags: debian

I am a beginner in linux. I use debian 11.
I have never managed to have sound on my pc because in the settings I only have the option "dummy output".
On alsamixer the chosen card is pulseaudio, I find it weird but if I choose another card it doesn't work either.
I tested this solution (https://ostechnix.com/fix-audio-issue-dummy-output-in-intel-nuc-on-debian-11/) but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT**

Here is what I get when I run the `dmesg` command after boot : https://pastebin.com/kLh9Cmze

Informations about my hardware :

- CPU : AMD Ryzen 5 4600h with radeon graphics × 12
- GPU : AMD Renoir
- OS : Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 64 bits

Output of `lspci` command :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer:

> On alsamixer the chosen card is pulseaudio

That is because Pulseaudio has a compatibility layer for ALSA-only applications: It pretends to be a ALSA sound card, so those applications can use this "soundcard" when in fact they are going through the compatibility layer.

> I have never managed to have sound

So this needs systematic debugging. ALSA provides all kernel sound drivers, go look at the `dmesg` output after boot and see what happens when your kernel tries to initialize the sound hardware.

If you don't understand what's going on in there, please capture all `dmesg` output after boot and upload it to a pastebin or similar, and edit your question with a link to this pastebin.

Please also edit your question and provide information about your hardware (do you actually have an Intel NUC, or is it just a random question you googled?). Also include the output of `lspci` (no images, please, copy text and indent by 4 spaces to properly format it) so we can at least see your basic hardware info.

Answer (score -1):

This guide worked for me:
https://ostechnix.com/fix-audio-issue-dummy-output-in-intel-nuc-on-debian-11/

However, issue returned after restart. A little more research, it seems the issue was generated by Home Assistant. I was able to fix it by using this:
https://github.com/OPHoperHPO/hassio-addons/tree/master/pulseaudio_fix

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.